# Parse Cloud Code: Can you pass objects in a push notification?

Tags: javascript, parsing, object, notifications, push

I'm creating a push notification similar to this sample code provided by Parse:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave('Activity', function(request) {

    if (request.object.get("type") === ("comment") {

        var message = request.user.get('displayName') + ': ';
        message += request.object.get('content').trim();

        var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
        query.equalTo('user', request.object.get("toUser"));

        Parse.Push.send({
            where:query,
            data: {
                alert: message,
                badge: 'Increment'
            }
        });
    }
});
```

My question is: in the data area of the Parse.Push.send, can I send an entire message object, where Message is a custom class I created? If so, what would that look like?

Comment: Did you figure it out? I also need this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the class created and saved an object why not just send the object ID and query it asynchronously once the user goes to retrieve the push notification?

The message object does not need to waste up space and be sent via push just a pointer is required.

I'm in the process of implementing something similar and this is the route I plan to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize the object in JSON/XML format and then deserialize it when you receive the push notification.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send objects directly. You'll get an exception (I had this issue a few days ago but didn't write the name of the exception down). The best answer is so far is by BrentonGray88.

I'm assuming you're not using Android because you included the badge: "Increment" value, but this is how I would do it:

**Android code to send the notification:**

Make sure the Comment object has a `pointer (_User) column` to the User who sent the comment. When you create the comment, include `user.put("commentAuthor", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());` in your Android code so that you can always access the user who created the comment.

Now you need to query the Comment to send its objectId through to the push notification.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<>("Comment");
query.whereEqualTo("objectId", I AM NOT SURE WHAT CONDITION YOU WANT HERE);
query.findInBackground((comment, e) -> {
    if (e == null) for (ParseObject commentObject: comment) {

       String recipientObjectId = commentObject.getParseObject("commentAuthor").getObjectId();

        final Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        // This is to send the notification to the author of the Comment
        params.put("recipientObjectId", recipientObjectId);

        // This is so we can use values from the Comment in the notification
        params.put("commentObjectId", commentObject.getObjectId());

        // This is a required lined
        params.put("useMasterKey", true);

        ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("pushMessage", params, new FunctionCallback<String>() {
            public void done(String result, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d(getClass().toString(), "ANNOUNCEMENT SUCCESS");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(e);
                    Log.d(getClass().toString(), "ANNOUNCEMENT FAILURE");
                }
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Now for the query in your **Cloude Code:**

```
  Parse.Cloud.define("pushMessage", function (request, response) {
      // Again, we are sending the notification to the author of the Comment
      var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
      pushQuery.equalTo('user', request.params.get("recipientObjectId"));

      // We retrieve information from the Comment created by that author
      var commentQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Comment);
      commentQuery.equalTo('objectId', request.params.commentObjectId);

       commentQuery.get("commentObjectId", {
           success: function(userObject) {
               var displayName = userObject.get("displayName");
               var content = userObject.get("content");

                var message = displayName + ': ';
                message += content.trim();

                Parse.Push.send({
                where: pushQuery,
                data: {
                    alert: message
                },
                }, {
                    useMasterKey: true,
                    success: function () {
                        response.success("Success!");
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    response.error("Error! " + error.message);
                }
            });

                console.log();
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log("An error occured :(");
            }
      });

  });
```

Sorry I'm not the best at JavaScript but that's kind of how I'd do it. Best of luck! :)